# Realm database doesn't Write data

Tags: java, android, realm

I was trying to write to db using realm but it does writes values. I also added

> apply plugin: 'android-apt' 
>   apply plugin: 'realm-android'

I'm using it in a Async Task. Below
How can I write correctly to realm database

```
protected Integer doInBackground(Integer[] p1)
{
    Realm.init(acti);
    RealmConfiguration otherConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().directory(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/xMapper/"+fileN)).build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(otherConfig);
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    for (File file:foxReaderLost)
    {   
        final byte[] x=utilz.compress(FileUtils.readFileToString(file));
        final String y=file.getName();

        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction(){
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm p1)
                {
                    IconModel icm=p1.createObject(IconModel.class);
                    icm.setName(y);
                    icm.setSource(x);
                }
            });
     }
}
```

**My RealmObject**

```
public class IconModel extends RealmObject {
    private byte[] msource;
    private String mname;

    public void setSource(byte[] lastName)
    {
        this.msource = lastName;
    }

    public void setName(String firstName)
    {
        this.mname = firstName;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's because your are using init in the async task. Try to init in you `App.java` and simply get realm instance with `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` in your async task

Comment: how to do that? Please tell me

Comment: see my answer below

Comment: Don't create a new Realm for each file O_o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Init your project, if you don't already have a class extending `Application` just create one.

```java
class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Realm.init(acti);
        RealmConfiguration otherConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().directory(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/xMapper/"+fileN)).build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(otherConfig);
    }
}
```

Then you just have to call `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` to get a realm object to query/insert/update/delete your database.